# How to small the h1 tag in a mobile bootstrap2.3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have just started bootstraps & i  have faced a problem.....!
I have an h1 tag at the top of my site. I design it up and check it out in a browser – looks great. Then I shrink it down to a mobile width, and the font is way too big! Here’s the thinking behind mobile first: how to small the same tag font in a mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use media queries.

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
   h1{
      font-size: 14px; /* or anything you want */
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to use a JavaScript library for responsive typefaces:

- [FlowType.js](http://simplefocus.com/flowtype/)
- [FitText.js](http://fittextjs.com/)